# Programmatically change initial size of NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, window

I wish to create a NSWindow with an initial size that is programmatically determined (as parameter to `[MyWindowController init:]`). My current approach is to call `[window setFrame:frame]` in `windowDidLoad` within the window controller, but the problem is that the window flashes briefly at the size specified in the nib file before it changes to its new size. I want to avoid this flash. Is it possible to set the initial size of an NSWindow programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Switch off "Visible At Launch" of the window and call `[MyWindowController showWindow:]` after you set the frame.